# Simple array usage demonstration

Tags: java, beginner, array

I just finished this code for my own practice purpose.  This code works just fine but I understand there still a lot insidious problems.  Any advice for improvement would be appreciated.  So here it goes:

```
Package DS;

import java.util.*; 

public class basic_Array {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int option;

    System.out.println("Welcome to basic array test, please choose your testing subject: ");

    Scanner user_option = new Scanner(System.in);


    do{

        System.out.println("Option 1: Simple one dimensional array.");
        System.out.println("Option 2: Simple two dimensional array. (under construction)");
        System.out.println("Option 0: Exit program");


        option = user_option.nextInt();
        System.out.println("current option is: " + option);

        switch(option){

        case 1:
            //simple array input method 
            simple_a1();
            break;
        case 2:
            simple_a2();
            break;
        }


    }while(option != 0);

    System.out.println("Program terminated...");
    user_option.close();

}

private static void simple_a1() {

    int[] a1 = new int[5];

    int in_num;                                                             //redundant but clear.

    Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){

        System.out.println("Request input for item " + i);
        in_num = user_input.nextInt();
        a1[i] = in_num;
        System.out.println("Got it, next one ");
    }

    System.out.println("The numbers in a1 are: ");

    for(int i2: a1){
        System.out.print(i2 + " ");
    }

    System.out.println("\nEnd of testing 1, back to main menu...");


}

private static void simple_a2() {

    System.out.println("This function still under construction, back to main menu...");
}

}
```

Edit in 2/26/2017:

Thanks for EBrown and others input, I've modified my program structure and added a few new functions.

I also have a question on multiple scanners I've put in my program. I did some search on it and many people says this is also a bad practice that may confuse the programmer in long run.  I think it cause the error when I trying to close the scanner object in simple_a1 method, so I only close the user_option scanner (located in main method).  So my question is: will it still cause resource leak?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's talk about SRP for the moment (I'm not going to cover anything else but this). SRP (or Single-Responsibility Principle) dictates that *each and every component of code should have exactly one responsibility*.

So we're going to look at all your code top-to-bottom and determine what responsibilities we have in each method.

We'll start with `main`:

1. Output information regarding programme definition to user;
2. Accept and process user input;
3. Call appropriate method(s) based on user input;

So that's more than one, but that's fine, we need to finish our analysis to make appropriate decisions on what to do next. Let's look at `simple_a1`:

1. Process items in an array;
2. Accept and process user input;
3. Add user input to array;
4. Print array information;
5. Inform the caller we're going back to the main menu;

That's a lot, and even `simple_a2` has *more than one* responsibility:

1. Inform the user the feature is not implemented;
2. Inform the user we are returning to the main menu;

What happens when we're not going back to the main menu again from either of those methods? Now you have *multiple* places that you have to modify, and in a larger, production application that would mean *very possible breakages*.

So we're going to eliminate responsibilities until each and every method only has one left.

Let's start with `simple_a1`:

We can take the following block and extract it to a new method:

> ```
> System.out.println("Request input for item " + i);
> in_num = user_input.nextInt();
> a1[i] = in_num;
> System.out.println("Got it, next one ");
> ```

This does *exactly one thing*: prompt the user for a number and store it in the array. We won't *store* it in the array in our sub-method, but we'll extract the prompting out. Let's create a new method:

```
private static int getNumber(Scanner input, int index) {
    System.out.println("Request input for item " + index);
    int result = input.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Got it");
    return result;
}
```

Perfect, so this has one responsibility. It's not the *prettiest*, but it will do. Next we have to implement this in our other method:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    a1[i] = getNumber(user_input, i);

    if (i + 1 < 5) {
        System.out.println(", next one");
    }
}
```

So now our input prompting is separated from our processing, that's good but we can do better.

The block is now something along the lines of:

> ```
> int[] a1 = new int[5];
> Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
>
> for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
>     a1[i] = getNumber(input, i);
>
>     if (i + 1 < 5) {
>         System.out.println(", next one");
>     }
> }
> ```

Well this whole block has one responsibility: build an array. So we can extract that out further:

```
private static int[] buildArray(int size) {
    int[] result = new int[5];
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        result[i] = getNumber(input, i);

        if (i + 1 < 5) {
            System.out.println(", next one");
        }
    }

    input.close();

    return result;
}
```

Good, so now `simple_a1` looks like:

> ```
> private static void simple_a1() {
>     int[] a1 = buildArray(5);
>
>     System.out.println("The numbers in a1 are: ");
>
>     for(int i2: a1){
>         System.out.print(i2 + " ");
>     }
>
>     System.out.println("\nEnd of testing 1, back to main menu...");
> }
> ```

But we still have *three* remaining responsibilities:

1. Build an array;
2. Print the array;
3. Inform the user we're going back to the main menu;

Well we can make a `printArray` method:

```
private static void printArray(int[] printArray) {
    for (int val : printArray) {
        System.out.print(val + " ");
    }
}
```

Then we finally finish `simple_a1`:

```
private static void simple_a1() {
    int[] a1 = buildArray(5);
    printArray(a1);
    System.out.print("\nEnd of testing 1");
}
```

So we're down to one responsibility: *process an array*. It's made up of steps, but the implementation for those steps *is not* part of `simple_a1`.

Next we'll fix `simple_a2`:

```
private static void simple_a2() {
    System.out.print("This function still under construction");
}
```

So we don't care *where* we return to, we only care that we're returning.

Finally, fixing `main` is easy:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Welcome to basic array test, please choose your testing subject: ");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    mainMenu(input);

    System.out.println("Program terminated...");
    input.close();
}

private static void mainMenu(Scanner input) {
    int option = 0;

    do {
        System.out.println("Option 1: Simple one dimensional array.");
        System.out.println("Option 2: Simple two dimensional array. (under construction)");
        System.out.println("Option 0: Exit program");

        option = user_option.nextInt();
        System.out.println("current option is: " + option);

        switch(option) {
            case 1:
                //simple array input method 
                simple_a1();
                break;
            case 2:
                simple_a2();
                break;
            case 0:
                return;
            // In C# the `case else` is `default`, not sure what Java's is
            default:
                System.out.print("Invalid option: " + option);
                break;
        }

        System.out.println(", back to main menu");
    } while (option != 0);
}
```

We've got all our major components separated, and we can *clearly* see what each section is supposed to do.

---

Overall, good start, I hope to see more from you here. :)

Answer (score 5):

#### `try-with-resources`

Since Java 7, you should use [`try-with-resources`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) for safe and efficient handling of your underlying I/O resources, i.e. `System.in`. This means you do not have to re-create a `Scanner` wrapper around it, or to explicitly call its `close()` method in the end.

#### Naming/styling convention

Java's default naming convention is `camelCase`, instead of `snake_case`. It's more important to keep to one convention consistently though, so it's fine *within* this question. :)

You may also want to give your methods more descriptive names, as `simple_a1()`/`simple_a2()` does not convey much information.

I also find that there's too much vertical whitespace in your code, it will be more readable if you can remove all the empty lines.

Comment: I agree with the white space suggestion, although I think that in this case it is a result of breaking the SRP, as demonstrated by EBrown's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Everything EBrown said with this ... minor exception ... the input close should precede the announcement that the program is done. I can not add comments or I would have simply made it a comment suggesting to EBrown the change.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Welcome to basic array test, please choose your testing subject: ");

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    mainMenu(input);

    input.close();

    System.out.println("Program terminated...");
}
```

Comment: Combine this with my answer and the one from h.j.k. and this programme becomes substantially better. :) +1